# Display array in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I prepare a web service returns an array:[image]

i need to display this list in sencha touch 2.Can someone help me to display the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ext.Ajax.request method (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/ajax), or you can directly use web service URL (Store -> proxy -> URL) with your store, Store should be JsonP, and don't forget to set rootProperty (like result/address) in your store -> proxy -> reader ->rootProperty.